# Laravel Eloquent method updateOrCreate exceeds execution time when updating

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

So the problem is that when I try to update my entity it finds it updates it but gets stuck in a loop probably and doesn't exit. When I check the database, even before the 60 seconds of execution time that I have expires, the values that I have changed are updated. 
If i constantly refresh (and here is where it gets crazy) the updated at values for other lectures starts to change every second while it executes this loop. 
When creating (not finding the id on the condition It creates it without a problem)

I have Lectures which looks like this:

```
class Lecture extends Model
{
use Searchable;
use SoftDeletes;

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $touches = ['themes', 'educationTypes', 'subjects'];


protected $fillable= [
    'name', 'description', 'user_id', 'field_id', 'approved'
];


public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saved(function ($model) {
        $model->themes->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->shouldBeSearchable();
        })->searchable();
    });
}



public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->with('companies');
}

public function geographies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Geography');
}

public function educationTypes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\EducationType', 'lecture_education_type')->withTimestamps();;
}

public function themes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Theme','lecture_theme', 'lecture_id', 'theme_id')->withTimestamps();;
}

public function subjects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject', 'lecture_subject')->withTimestamps();;
}

public function cases(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\CompanyCase' ,
        'case_company_lecture',
        'lecture_id',
        'case_id',
        'id',
        'id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function companies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Company' ,
        'case_company_lecture',
        'lecture_id',
        'company_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}

public function field(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Field');
}

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $this->themes;
    $this->user;
    $this->educationTypes;
    $this->subjects;
    $this->geography;

    return $this->toArray();

 }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
    public function storeLecture(Request $request) {
    $lecture_id = $request->get('lecture_id');

    // It gets stuck between the comments
    $lecture = Lecture::updateOrCreate(['id' => $lecture_id],
    [
        'name'=> request('name'),
        'description'=> request('description'),
        'user_id'=> request('user_id')]
    );
    // and doesn't update the themes, edu types subjects and etc.

    $company_id = $request->get('company_id');
    $company = Company::find(request('company_id'));
    $lecture->companies()->sync([$company->id]);

    $eduTypes= $request->get('education_types');
    $themes= $request->get('themes');
    $subjects = $request->get('subjects');
    $geographies = $request->get('geographies');

    $lecture->themes()->sync($themes);
    $lecture->educationTypes()->sync($eduTypes);
    $lecture->subjects()->sync($subjects);
    $lecture->geographies()->sync($geographies);

    $n1 = new Notification();
    $n1->send(request('user_id'), 1, 'new_lecture', $lecture->id);


    $user = User::where('id', $request->id)->first();
    $user_with_companies = $user->load('companies');
    $slug = $user_with_companies->companies->first()->slug;
    return response(['success' => true]);
}
```

This is the frontend method sending the request (in between I have a middleware checking if the user is admin (possible to create a lecture) based on the this.selectedExpert.id, which doesn't interfere).

```
    createUpdateLecture() {
  const url = `${window.location.origin}/lecture/create/${
    this.selectedExpert.id
  }`;
  this.$http
    .post(url, {
      education_types: this.allEducationTypes
        .filter(el => el.checked)
        .map(a => a.id),
      themes: this.allThemes.filter(el => el.checked).map(a => a.id),
      geographies: this.allGeographies
        .filter(el => el.checked)
        .map(a => a.id),
      subjects: this.allSubjects.filter(el => el.checked).map(a => a.id),
      name: this.lecture.name,
      description: this.lecture.description,
      user_id: this.selectedExpert.id,
      company_id: this.company.id,
      lecture_id: this.lecture.id
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.$parent.showLectureCreateModal = false;
      // window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

As I can see what is happening I probably use the method really badly but I just want to understand it better for further usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of researching and testing it turns out that **it is not the updateOrCreate method** causing the problem because I tried with two different functions for creating and updating and the update function was still having the same problem.

The problem is created from Algolia which is used for searching based on different fields in the platform. Fx. in Themes

```
class Theme extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

use Searchable;
protected $touches = ['lectures'];

public  function lectures(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lecture');
}

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $this->lectures;
    return $this->toArray();
}
}
```

Removing the searchable from the models did the trick!